# Any way of knowing whether section was just added in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am applying a fading color highlight to cells just added to a `UITableView`, however it is also being applied when cells that were added earlier get scrolled into view for the first time (e.g. if more than a page's worth of items were added in one go.)

My question is, is it possible to determine whether `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called because the section was recently added, or if it is because it was scrolled into view the first time?

Alternatively, is it possible within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to tell if the cell being shown *will* be visible or not?

---

Edit: I managed to accomplish this by applying a flag to the datasource once an item had existed for more than a single update (I frequently update my data, so before adding any new items to the list, I simply marked all existing objects in the source as 'old').

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That certainly sounds like a good way to go about it. I have been putting off subclassing the cell for the time being so I could spend the time improving the base functionality, but I definitely need to restyle the cell at some point, so perhaps this is the prod I need to get that done.

Comment: @Jeremy - I don't see how that will work, since iOS will recycle cells at will.  The only way to keep some reasonably persistent per-row info is to have a separate array for it.

Comment: @Jeremy this would not work. If you are using cell reuse properly then once you have made enough cells to fill the tableView's visible area no new ones will be made regardless of how many thousands of items you may be displaying, this is the point of cell reuse.

Comment: Yeah, cell reuse is like an escalator -- as steps disappear at one end they reappear at the other.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments guys! Thankfully I didn't head down that route, and applied a value to my data source instead. I simply set an 'old' flag on each item before I update the list, so only brand new rows end up fading in, and those unseen upon first addition will be marked as old during the next update. (Not sure how much sense any of that made out of context, but basically I achieved what I was trying to accomplish at the data source)

Comment: Thats exactly the way to go, play with the dataSource.